# Android WorkManager: PeriodicWorkRequest is not executing or its executed once

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I'm implementing a class for a background tasks using workmanager. The task is periodic so I'm using PeriodicWorkRequest, but task is not exectuing or its executed once.
Here is class, what is wrong ?

```java
public class PollingWorker extends Worker {

    private final static String DELAY_KEY = "initialDelayDuration";
    private final static String TAG_POLLING_WORK_KEY = "background_polling_tag";
    private final static int DEFAULT_DELAY = 20000;

    public PollingWorker(
            @Nonnull Context ctx,
            @Nonnull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(ctx, params);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        try{
            Log.d("TEST","sending work");
            return Result.success();
        }catch (Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e("TEST", "Error applying blur", throwable);
            return Result.failure();
        }

    }

    public static void startPollingWorker(
            @Nonnull Context context,
            final long interval,
            final String pollingWorkerTag
    ) {

        Log.d("TEST","interval:"+interval);
        Log.d("TEST","pollingWorkerTag:"+pollingWorkerTag);

        PeriodicWorkRequest pollingWorkerRequest =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(PollingWorker.class,interval,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .addTag(pollingWorkerTag)
                        .build();

        Operation operationResult=WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(pollingWorkerTag,ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,pollingWorkerRequest);
        Log.d("TEST","operation result:"+operationResult.getResult().isDone());
        Log.d("TEST","operation result:"+operationResult.getResult().isCancelled());
    }
}
```

The logs from this are:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to replace work manager instead of keeping the existing work manager.

```
 private void setUpWorkManager() {
    WorkManager mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context);
    mWorkManager.cancelAllWorkByTag(BACKGROUND);
    PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(PeriodicWorker.class, PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .addTag(BACKGROUND)
            .build();
    mWorkManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(BACKGROUND, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Periodical worker does not have either a success or failure state.
Your worker is actually running, So your code

```
Log.d("TEST","operation result:"+operationResult.getResult().isDone());
```

Will never become true

In the log, you should find `Worker result SUCCESS for Work` which means the worker is running, but you can't get the success state by `operationResult.getResult().isDone()` because the state of periodical worker will be enqueued for the next time.

You can observe the work by using `getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workerId)`. as follows:

```
WorkManager.getInstance(ctx).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workerId).observe(lifecycleScope, workInfo -> {
        Log.d("TEST", "worker listened state: " + workInfo.getState());
    });
```

To get the id use `UUID workerId = pollingWorkerRequest.getId();`

Then you will find the changing state of your worker.
RUNNING, ENQUEUED